# extending mui (material ui) date picker component typscript issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I try to extend the muiv5 date picker component like this

I named it `DSDesktopDatePicker`

codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/materialuipickers-material-demo-forked-4oofbx?file=/demo.tsx

```js
import DesktopDatePicker, {
  DesktopDatePickerProps,
} from "@mui/lab/DesktopDatePicker";

export const DSDesktopDatePicker = (props: DesktopDatePickerProps) => {
  return <DesktopDatePicker {...props} />;
};
```

and I will use it like this

```js
export const Debug = () => {
  return (
    <DSDesktopDatePicker
      value={new Date()}
      onChange={evt => console.log(evt)}
    />
  );
};
```

From what I understand and read. how mui will handle the type of the value on the `onChange` props is the component will read what type of the value passed to `value` props.

In this case `new Date()`

[image: attachment of Desktop Date Picker uses]

If we pass a string on value props. the first param of `onChange` props will also be a string type

[image: DesktopDatePicker with value stringz]

#### My issue is

I extend the date picker component and spread all the props to my new component,
When I try to use it, the component fails to read what type of the value passed to `value` props and the `onChange` props will also fail to read the value types.

in this case, the types of the value will remain as `unknown`

[image: DSDesktopDatePicker unknown value]

##### What I expected

is that when I extend the component it will still succeed to read the value and all the props still work the same as the base component `DesktopDatePicker`

##### What I have tried

I try to look at the documentation but still couldn't find anything related until now.